# Transit gateway, two vpcs, one with vpn connection. No routing from second vpc to network behind vpn

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, strongswan, aws-vpc-peering, transit-gateway

I have a following scenario:

VPC 1:

- 10.100.0.0/16 instance with strongswan with ipsec tunnel to 192.168.0.0/24
- route to 192.168.0.0/24 through strongswan instance

VPC 2:

- 172.16.0.0/24

Transit gateway:

- VPC 1 attached
- VPC 2 attached
- Route to VPC1 through Attachment 1 (VPC1)
- Route to VPC2 through Attachment 1 (VPC2)
- Route to IPSEC network (192.168.0.0/24) through Attachment 1 (VPC1)

Added routing:

- VPC1 Route table has static route to VPC2 CIDR through transit
  gateway
- VPC2 Route table has static route to VPC1 CIDR through transit
  gateway
- VPC2 Route table has static route to IPSEC network (192.168.0.0/24)
  through transit gateway

Problem:

- Communication between VPC1 and VPC2 works perfect
- Communiaction from VPC1 to ipsec network (192.168.0.0/24) works
  perfect
- **Communication from VPC2 to ipsec network (192.168.0.0/24) does not
  work**

what can be wrong?

Comment: How does Strongswan? on an EC2?

Comment: Yes, EC2 instance in VPC1

Comment: Are the SG and NACL rules set to receive traffic from `172.16.0.0/24` on that instance and the subnet?